# TFS to VSTS Migration info needed

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am Currently working on TFS migration from TFS 2015 U3 to TFS 2018 RTM--->VSTS

Here are my concerns,
 1. If the extensions migrate to TFS 2018, When i migrate tfs 2018 ---> VSTS, Would it possible to migrate those to  VSTS (EX:SSIS Deploy,SSRS Deployment)?
 2. Would it be possible to get all the customized data on the TFS project dashboard after the migration to VSTS?
3. As per MSDN, For the migration of TFS2018 ---> VSTS, We need to use "TFS Migration Tool" , May i know where can we install the tool and how to process the migration using it?
4.Once we migrate to VSTS, If I want to use GIT, Is there anyway to use it as a source control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To migrate TFS on-premise server to VSTS, there are three [Migration options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/migrate-to-vsts-from-tfs?view=vsts):

- Option 1: Copy the most important assets manually
- Option 2: High fidelity database migration
- Option 3: Using public API-based tools for higher fidelity migration

According to your requirement, suggest you use option 2, the TFS/VSTS product team provides a high fidelity TFS Database Import Service. A downloadable Migration Guide is available at https://aka.ms/TFSImportData.

Because the TFS Database Import Service operates at a database level, it can provide a very high fidelity migration. If you want to move your existing TFS data into VSTS, we strongly recommend using this option.

More details please refer this tutorial: [Migrate data from TFS to VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/migration-overview?view=vsts).

After the database level migration,  the customized data on the project dashboard will also be stored. Not sure about the extension, however you could download them from [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vsts) or upload your customize extension to VSTS again even lose them.

Besides, you could  use git as source control in VSTS. Simply create a team project and select **Git** as version control, also take a look at: [Get Started with Git and VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/gitquickstart?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio)